# GetIpErrorString - How can I get localized strings?

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, ping, icmp

There is function [GetIpErrorString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The function retrieves an IP Helper error strings in English.

How can I get such strings in current locale?

Comment: What happens if you directly call FormatMessage?

Comment: Should be possible, since `GetIpErrorString()` is just a wrapper that calls `FormatMessage()` internally.

Comment: `FormatMessage` gives other messages